# Does Domain Parameters in ECDSA are same?

Tags: ecdsa

In **ECDSA**,
Signer and `Verifier` should have same a, b and G?
such that y^2 = x^3 + ax + b, G is starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the signer and verifier of an ECDSA message must agree on the curve parameters ahead of time.  Several curves are named and defined in [SEC2](http://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf).